# re-slicing 2d slice in go

Tags: go, slice

I came across a problem which needed editing several indexes of a 2-dimensional slice.

Imagine the following numbers as a 2-d slice of slices `a [][]int`

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

The problem is that I want to **access** and **modify**

```
0 1
1 2
```

As a sub-slice and I want **a to be changed as well**. I achieved that with this code :

```
sub := a[:2]
for i := range sub {
    sub[i] = sub[i][:2]
}
```

Now `fmt.Println(sub)` prints `[[0 1] [1 2]]` But the problem is `fmt.Println(a)` is printing `[[0 1] [1 2] [2 3 4 5] [3 4 5 6]]`

**The question is**, how can I access this sub-slice without losing any data?

Comment: The for loop modifies the original slice.  Copy to a new slice.

Comment: @CeriseLimón sorry, just edited the question. I want my original slice to be modified as I modify my sub-slice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal to modify the original []int slice elements when using `sub`, then copy the elements of `a` to a new slice.  The code in the question modifies `a` directly.

```
sub := make([][]int, 2)
for i := range sub {
    sub[i] = a[i][:2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution but don't know if it's the right way of doing so

```
sub := make([][]int, 2)
for i := range sub {
    sub[i] = a[i][:2]
}
sub[0][0] = "876"
fmt.Println(a)
fmt.Println(sub)
```

now in the output I have

```
[[876 1 2 3] [1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 5] [3 4 5 6]]
[[876 1] [1 2]]
```